# Nearby Bus Stops on Google Maps on Android

Tags: android, maps, esri

Is there anyway to query Google Maps to get the list of bus stops (Bus stop Id, Bus stop name) nearby based a user's current location?

I was able to get the ESRI Shape File from http://www.mytransport.sg/. However, I have no idea how to use integrate these files into android. I read that we can integrate the data from the ESRI Shape File into Google Maps using FusionTable. I've done that but I have no idea how to integrate the FusionTable into my Android application. I am also not sure about how to get these bus stops based on the user's current location in the FusionTable maps.

Am I going on the right track? Are there any other options for me to get these bus stops information?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Use below Google API to find out your near bus stop locations

> Here you have to send your current latitude and longitude values then only able to get your near bus stop location details.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=13.0611704,80.28284059999999&radius=3&types=bus_station&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyDveM91dVZcXP3wwYLcZN-VwLsGJVMMM8g
```

and it will return like this

```
{
"html_attributions" : [],
"results" : [
  {
     "geometry" : {
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 13.06117,
           "lng" : 80.282841
        }
     },
     "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
     "id" : "22b35bb733cc9e31e47f6e17aa57024be399b037",
     "name" : "Marina Beach Bus Stop",
     "place_id" : "ChIJx31rGKJoUjoR2_i4-OMdm14",
     "reference" : "CnRoAAAAKny_7uv5-1qhaZSaAkvbjglDqUercO9ENnINjJnzMx4ghUp2q6bl-glbWFXhvEsDynoDSIQ2yt8e7g2sxZme6K7nB-KmSF73KwDCqtQoOe-gBlGP1U-85JHZ4WYAZl3DfCfWrecAqkOH5zR178fG4xIQOFKOviTy6NFoMHQkDsjiaRoURHbKHKxg2YjYEPUVOqu5Yr946xM",
     "scope" : "GOOGLE",
     "types" : [ "bus_station", "transit_station", "establishment" ],
     "vicinity" : "Kamarajar Promenade, Marina Beach, Triplicane, Chennai"
  }
],
"status" : "OK" 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Although this does returns the bus stops nearby, it doesn't return the Stop ID seen here https://www.google.com.sg/maps/place/Marina+Bay+Sands+Hotel/@1.2838785,103.8589899,17z/data=!4m7!1m4!3m3!1s0x31da1906f8b7719b:0x3b6284d2af1c7c!2sMarina+Bay+Sands,+10+Bayfront+Ave,+Singapore+018956!3b1!3m1!1s0x31da19043805318f:0xd1610965e5e8eab2

Comment: Yup. But i need the Stop ID because I will be using it to query for other information from the server.

Comment: i have no idea to get stop ID, i will try how to get stop ID in google API if i found any solution i will comment here.

Comment: Is it possible to get the Bus stops between two places via api , I am unable to find the api parameters for it ...